# DataTemplate with Border needs to change Background based on parent control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

The border of a datatemplate inside a control needs to change its background brush depending on situation.

Since my code is at work and I am home trying to recall the structure, apology for pseudo coding.

It looks something like:

```
<parent control>

 <custom:controlwithdatatemplate needs Border background to be green/>

 <custom:controlwithdatatemplate needs Border background to be red/>

</parent conrol>
```

In the datatemplate:

```
<dataTemplate>

 <Border Background="{Binding RelativeSource, findancestor x:Type Border??}"

</dataTemplate>
```

So my guess is set the binding condition of border dynamic (maybe find ancestor of Border Type). But Since Setting the Border style at parent control might not piped down to the datatemplate of child xaml, I am not sure if this is correct approach.  Is exposing brush as dependency property the only way?  Can I somehow provide two different resource or style at the parent xaml and each datatemplate of the control to bind to differnt resource/style in the parent xaml?

-----------EDIT-------------------

Although I was looking for another way than using dependency property, I still chose the answer from threads below since it resolves the above issue and can't think of any better way for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Border Background="{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Border}}}" />
```

EDIT-------------------------------------

So after clarifying:

```
<ParentControl>
   <ParentControl.Resources>
       <SolidColorBrush x:Key=firstBrush Color="Red" />
       <SolidColorBrush x:Key=secondBrush Color="Blue" />
    </ParentControl.Resources>

    <ChildControl BorderBrush="{DynamicResource firstBrush} />
    <ChildControl BorderBrush="{DynamicResource secondBrush} />

</ParentControl>

<ChildControl>
 <DataTemplate>
  <...>
   <Border Background="{Binding Path=BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ParentControl}}}" />
  </...>
 </DataTemplate>
</ChildControl>
```

Inside the ChildControl you will need to define a DP of Type Brush.

Comment: Then how should I declare the border at the parent xaml? Using dependecy property?

Comment: Just put a border in the parent. The FindAncestor just finds the next border above the element in the tree...

Comment: Defining a DP btw is a more reliable way to find the element, so that's recommended. :)

Comment: But the parent's border should not be the same color. Maybe in the style of parent xaml and bind to style?

Comment: In your sample both elements will have the same color. If you put the control in different parent controls, with different colors they will adopt to them. Maybe I did not understand how you want to define the color for a control

Comment: you are correct in that both childs will have same color if they both get the border color from parent's border. So I need two distinct color defined in the parent for each control. How can I do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55170/discussion-between-gope-and-jp-medevice).

Comment: Your answer is too brief. Please provide more detail, explaining how this addresses the question.

Comment: @Gili... actually its not, but we continued in a private chat as SO was suggesting.
I will edit my answer though, because the world needs to know! ;)

Comment: I edited the post based on our chat :) After the edit is applied to above post after peer review, let me acknowledge your contribution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think, you looking for datatrigger,

```
           <DataTemplate>
                <Border Background="Red" x:Name="bor"/>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type YouParentType}}}"
                             Value="SomeValue">
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                Value="Green"
                                TargetName="bor" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: No the datatemplate's border color should change based on parent's desire, not by internal state change.

Comment: I think this is helpful in its own way for datatrigger with relativesource binding, but does not fit to be answer for the specific question above.